# How to organize and print the values of an array in java?

Tags: java, arrays

I hava created a program with a for-loop that determines the number of arrays created. I had to organize each arrey in ascending order, so I created another class that do this (**Organizer**), **but I dont know how to export each array (array code in the main class)**

Once I orginised the arreys I need to calculate and print the results of the arrays values.

Here is an example of what the output have to looks like.

if the arrey value is the same the total value adds 10

if the arrey value is a squence the total value adds 20

> Input rounds: 4
>
> Round 1 --> 1 3 7 total value: 11
>
> Round 2 --> 1 4 5 total value: 10
>
> Round 3 --> 1 1 1 total value: 13
>
> Round 4 --> 1 2 3 total value: 26

**PS I am new at java.I think I am close to the solution but I can't figure out how to overcome this problem**

**Organizer Class**

```
public class Organizer {
     // ---------------------- ATTRIBUTES ---------------------
     protected int rand1;
     protected int rand2;
     protected int rand3;

     // ------------------ CONSTRUCTOR -------------------
     public Organizer(int o1, int o2, int o3) {
          // This puts the three values from arrey in ascending order.
          int tmp;
          if (o2 < o1) {
              tmp = o2;
              o2 = o1;
              o1 = tmp;
          }
          if (o3 < o2) {
              tmp = o3;
              o3 = o2;
              o2 = tmp;
          }
          if (o2 < o1) {
              tmp = o2;
              o2 = o1;
              o1 = tmp;
          }
          rand1 = o1;
          rand2 = o2;
          rand3 = o3;
     }

     // --------------------- METHODS ---------------------
     // Accessor methods
     public int getRand1() {
          return rand1;
     }

     public int getRand2() {
          return rand2;
     }

     public int getRand3() {
          return rand3;
     }

     // Will return true if all values are the same. 
     // This depends on the values being ordered.
     public boolean threeSame() {
          return (rand1 == rand3);
     }

     // Will return true if we have a run e.g. "one, two, three", or "four, five, six".
     // Again, this depends upon the values being ordered.  
     public boolean sequence() {
          return (( (rand1 + 1) == rand2) && ( (rand2 + 1) == rand3));
     }


     public void printResult() {
          if (threeSame())
              System.out.println("The values are all the same.");
          else if (sequence())
              System.out.println("The values are a sequence.");

    }

}
```

**Calculator Class**

```
public class Calculator extends Organizer {

public static int totalValue;

   public void calcSumOfValues(int s1, int s2, int s3) {
     int sumOfArrey;
   sumOfArrey= s1 + s2 + s3;
   }
    public void calcSumOfExtraValues(int sumOfArrey) {
            if (threeSame())
              totalValue= sumOfArrey + 10;
            else if (sequence())
              totalValue= sumOfArrey + 20;
            else
              totalValue= sumOfArrey
   }
        public void printResult() {
          System.out.println("round " + (r+1) + "--> " + randomArray [i] + "Total value" + totalValue  );
        }
   }
```

**Main Class**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class UserClass {

  // ------------------- FIELDS ------------------------    
        // Create instance of Scanner class
        public static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        // variables
        public static Organizer orga;
        public static Calculator calc;

        public static int randomArray [];

    // ------------------ METHODS ------------------------  
        public static void main(String[] args) {

        int rounds; // input by user

        System.out.print("Please input number of rounds (grater or equal than 0) --> ");
        rounds = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("\n");

        for (int r = 0; r < rounds; r++) {  // loop for number of rounds
        int randomArray [] = new int [3];
        for (int i = 0; i < randomArray.length; i++) { // loop for random Array 
        randomArray [i] = (int)(Math.random()*8);   
        }               
        }

        // Create new organizer and calculator instances
        orga = new Organizer(randomArray [0], randomArray [1], randomArray [2]);
        calc = new Calculator();

        //Calculate
        calc.getRand1();
        calc.getRand2();
        calc.getRand3();
        calc.threeSame();
        calc.sequence();
        calc.calcSumOfValues();     
        calc.calcSumOfExtraValues();

    }//end Main Method  
}// end Class
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to make just 1 2D array and then pass its one row at a time to do your computation.

Comment: could you give me an example

Comment: you may declare a 2D array like

Comment: int arr[][]=new int[rounds][3]

Comment: then you can pass its one row  at a time using for loop and generate numbers accordlingly

Answer (score 0):

To export array from Organizer, you can simply write an accessor method int[] getOrderedRandArray() that create a new instance of array initialized by the sorted value rand1, rand2, rand3.

```html
public class Organizer {
     // ---------------------- ATTRIBUTES ---------------------
     protected int rand1;
     protected int rand2;
     protected int rand3;

     // --------------------- METHODS ---------------------
     // ... your code ...
     public int[] getOrderedRandArray(){
         int[] orderedRandArray = new int[]{rand1, rand2, rand3};
         return orderedRandArray;
     }
    
     // ... your code ...

}
```